# Angular 2 - formControlName inside component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to create a custom input component that I can use with the FormBuilder API. How do I add `formControlName` inside a component?

Template:

```html
<label class="custom-input__label"
          *ngIf="label">
        {{ label }}
</label>
<input class="custom-input__input" 
       placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
       name="title" />
<span class="custom-input__message" 
      *ngIf="message">
        {{ message }}
</span>
```

Component:

```ts
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'custom-input',
    host: {
        '[class.custom-input]': 'true'
    },
    templateUrl: 'input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['input.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class InputComponent {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() message: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
}
```

Usage:

```html
<custom-input label="Title" 
           formControlName="title" // Pass this to input inside the component>
</custom-input>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar; did the answer @p-moloney gave provide all the info you needed? If so, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: I just did something similar.
instead of trying to pass the name in `formControlName`, I passed directly the `FormControl` Object with `formControl="formControlObject"` to the custom-input. (with an `@Input formControlObject : FormControl`).

Comment: I recommend the article https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel which explains this very well.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should not be adding `formControlName` attribute to the input field in the template of your custom component. 
You should be adding the `formControlName` on the custom-input element itself as per the best practice.

Here what you can use in your custom-input component is the `controlValueAccessor` interface  to make your custom-input have the value updated whenever there is an event of input field in the template of your custom input  changed or blurred.

It provides a connection (to update values or other needs) between the form control behavior of your custom input and the UI you are providing for that custom form control.

**Below is the code of a custom input component in TypeScript.**

```ts
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, AfterViewInit, trigger, state, animate, transition, style, HostListener, OnChanges, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'inv-input',
  templateUrl:'./input-text.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    animations:[trigger(
        'visibilityChanged',[
            state('true',style({'height':'*','padding-top':'4px'})),
            state('false',style({height:'0px','padding-top':'0px'})),
            transition('*=>*',animate('200ms'))
        ]
    )]
})

export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

    // Input field type eg:text,password
    @Input()  type = "text"; 

    // ID attribute for the field and for attribute for the label
    @Input()  idd = ""; 

    // The field name text . used to set placeholder also if no pH (placeholder) input is given
    @Input()  text = ""; 

    // placeholder input
    @Input()  pH:string; 

    //current form control input. helpful in validating and accessing form control
    @Input() c:FormControl = new FormControl(); 

    // set true if we need not show the asterisk in red color
    @Input() optional : boolean = false;

    //@Input() v:boolean = true; // validation input. if false we will not show error message.

    // errors for the form control will be stored in this array
    errors:Array<any> = ['This field is required']; 

    // get reference to the input element
    @ViewChild('input')  inputRef:ElementRef; 


    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnChanges(){

    }

    //Lifecycle hook. angular.io for more info
    ngAfterViewInit(){ 
        // set placeholder default value when no input given to pH property      
        if(this.pH === undefined){
            this.pH = "Enter "+this.text; 
        }

        // RESET the custom input form control UI when the form control is RESET
        this.c.valueChanges.subscribe(
            () => {
                // check condition if the form control is RESET
                if (this.c.value == "" || this.c.value == null || this.c.value == undefined) {
                    this.innerValue = "";      
                    this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = "";                 
                }
            }
        );
    }

   //The internal data model for form control value access
    private innerValue: any = '';

    // event fired when input value is changed . later propagated up to the form control using the custom value accessor interface
    onChange(e:Event, value:any){
        //set changed value
        this.innerValue = value;
        // propagate value into form control using control value accessor interface
        this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);

        //reset errors 
        this.errors = [];
        //setting, resetting error messages into an array (to loop) and adding the validation messages to show below the field area
        for (var key in this.c.errors) {
            if (this.c.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if(key === "required"){
                    this.errors.push("This field is required");
                }else{
                    this.errors.push(this.c.errors[key]);
                }              
            }
        }
    }



    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
        }
    }

    //propagate changes into the custom form control
    propagateChange = (_: any) => { }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.innerValue = value;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {

    }
}
```

**Below is the template HTML for the custom input component**

```xhtml
<div class="fg">
      <!--Label text-->
      <label [attr.for]="idd">{{text}}<sup *ngIf="!optional">*</sup></label>
      <!--Input form control element with on change event listener helpful to propagate changes -->
      <input type="{{type}}" #input id="{{idd}}" placeholder="{{pH}}" (blur)="onChange($event, input.value)">
      <!--Loop through errors-->
      <div style="height:0px;" [@visibilityChanged]="!c.pristine && !c.valid" class="error">
            <p *ngFor="let error of errors">{{error}}</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Below is  custom input component which can be used in a fromGroup or individually**

```xhtml
<inv-input formControlName="title" [c]="newQueryForm.controls.title" [optional]="true" idd="title" placeholder="Type Title to search"
          text="Title"></inv-input>
```

In this fashion if you implement your custom form controls you can apply your custom validator directives easily and accumulate the errors on that form control to display your errors.

One can imitate the same style to develop custom select component, radio button group, checkbox, textarea, fileupload etc in the above fashion with minor changes as per what the form control's behavior demands.

Comment: Awesome dude!!! by the way, i find it odd that there is a method called registerOnTouched for touch events on the ControlValueAccessor interface, why is that?

Comment: The registerOnTouched function accepts a callback function which you can call when you want to set your control to touched. This is then managed by Angular 2 by adding the correct touched state and classes to the actual element tag in the DOM.  ref: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Your answer inspired me for a similar solution. But I delegate instead of implementing it on my own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890273/395879

Comment: I had to use this in combination with https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83 You need to register your value accessor as a provider. I found another post that said to do it in the app.module, but I for some reason couldn't get that to work. The moment I put it in the component declaration itself, everything worked fine :)

Comment: You saved my life!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 21):

Angular 8 and 9:
Use viewProvider in you custom component. Working example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
    viewProviders: [
        {
            provide: ControlContainer,
            useExisting: FormGroupDirective
        }
    ]
})
```

Now, when you assign formControlName, your component will attach itself to the parent form.

```
<input matInput formControlName="{{name}}">
```

or

```
<input matInput [formControlName]='name'>
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution. Does anyone have more resources on this?

Comment: Found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893088/forwarding-formcontrolname-to-inner-component-in-angular), worth trying

Comment: Can you please complete this, how to input and consume this property?

Answer (score 16):

The main idea here is that you have to link the FormControl to the FormGroup, this can be done be passing the FormGroup to each input component...

So your input template might look something like the following:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <label *ngIf="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <input [formControlName]="inputName" />
    <span *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</span>
</div>
```

Where the `@Input`'s for the input component will be `form`, `label`, `inputName` and `message`.

It would be used like this:

```
<form [FormGroup]="yourFormGroup">
    <custom-input
        [form]="yourFormGroup"
        [inputName]="thisFormControlName"
        [message]="yourMessage"
        [label]="yourLabel">
    </custom-input>
</form>
```

For more info on custom Form Input Components I would recomend taking a look through [Angular's Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html).
Also if you want more information on how to get the `@Input` and `@Output` working take a look through the [Angular Docs Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: the above answer generate the following error "Can't bind to 'formControlName' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

Comment: Make a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) replicating this issue and I'll help you troubleshoot as I can

Comment: The problem here is that there is a form wrapper for each input which is not ideal

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated, Angular now has [`FormGroupName`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroupName-directive.html) which works similar to `FormControlName`, i.e. instead of wrapping each input it simply adds a pointer to the `FormGroup` in theroy

Answer (score 3):

I'm solving this in a similar way like [web-master-now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42744166/395879). But instead of writing a complete own `ControlValueAccessor` I'm delegating everything to an inner `<input>` `ControlValueAccessor`. The result is a much shorter code and I don't have to handle the interaction with the `<input>` element on my own.

### Here is my code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field',
  template: `    
    <label>
      {{label}}
      <input ngDefaultControl type="text" >
    </label>
    `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormFieldComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class FormFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() label: String;
  @Input() formControlName: String;
  @ViewChild(DefaultValueAccessor) valueAccessor: DefaultValueAccessor;

  delegatedMethodCalls = new ReplaySubject<(_: ControlValueAccessor) => void>();

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.delegatedMethodCalls.subscribe(fn => fn(this.valueAccessor));
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.delegatedMethodCalls.next(valueAccessor => valueAccessor.registerOnChange(fn));
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.delegatedMethodCalls.next(valueAccessor => valueAccessor.registerOnTouched(fn));
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.delegatedMethodCalls.next(valueAccessor => valueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled));
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.delegatedMethodCalls.next(valueAccessor => valueAccessor.writeValue(obj));
  }
}
```

### How does it work?

Generally this won't work, as a simpel `<input>` won't be a `ControlValueAccessor` without `formControlName`-directive, which is not allowed in the component due to missing `[formGroup]`, as others already pointed out. However if we look at Angular's code for the `DefaultValueAccessor` implementation

```
@Directive({
    selector:
        'input:not([type=checkbox])[formControlName],textarea[formControlName],input:not([type=checkbox])[formControl],textarea[formControl],input:not([type=checkbox])[ngModel],textarea[ngModel],[ngDefaultControl]',

    //...
})
export class DefaultValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
```

... we can see that there is another attribute selector `ngDefaultControl`. It's available for a different purpose, but it seems to be supported officially.

A little disadvantage is that the `@ViewChild` query result with the value accessor will be available not before the `ngAfterViewInit` handler is called. (It will be available earlier depending on your template, but that's not supported officially .)

That's why I'm buffering all calls we want to delegate to our inner `DefaultValueAccessor` using a `ReplaySubject`. A `ReplaySubject` is an `Observable`, which buffers all events and emits them on subscription. A normal `Subject` would throw them away until subscription.

We emit lambda expressions representing the actual call that can be executed later. On `ngAfterViewInit` we subscribe to our `ReplaySubject` and simply call the received lambda functions.

I'm sharing two other ideas here, as they are very important for my own projects and it took me a while to work everything out. I see a lot of people having similar problems and use cases, so I hope this is useful for you:

### Idea for improvement 1: Provide the `FormControl` for the view

I replaced the `ngDefaultControl` by `formControl` in my project, so we can pass the `FormControl` instance to the inner `<input>`. This is not useful by itself, however it is if you are using other directives which interact with `FormControl`s, such as Angular Material's [`MatInput`](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview). E.g. if we replace our `form-field` template by...

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input [placeholder]="label" [formControl]="formControl>
    <mat-error>Error!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

...Angular Material is able to automatically show errors set in the form control.

I have to adjust the component in order to pass the form control. I retrieve the form control from our `FormControlName` directive:

```
export class FormFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterContentInit {
  // ... see above

  @ContentChild(FormControlName) private formControlNameRef: FormControlName;
  formControl: FormControl;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.formControl = <FormControl>this.formControlNameRef.control;
  }

  // ... see above
}
```

You should also adjust your selector to require the `formControlName` attribute: `selector: 'form-field[formControlName]'`.

### Idea for improvement 2: Delegate to a more generic value accessor

I replaced the `DefaultValueAccessor` `@ViewChild` query by a query for all `ControlValueAccessor` implementations. This allows other HTML form controls than `<input>` like `<select>` and  is useful if you want to make your form control type configurable.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'form-field',
    template: `    
    <label [ngSwitch]="controlType">
      {{label}}
      <input *ngSwitchCase="'text'" ngDefaultControl type="text" #valueAccessor>
      <select *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" ngModel #valueAccessor>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </select>
    </label>
    `,
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormFieldComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class FormFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    // ... see above

    @Input() controlType: String = 'text';
    @ViewChild('valueAccessor', {read: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR}) valueAccessor: ControlValueAccessor;

    // ... see above
}
```

Usage example:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <form-field formControlName="firstName" label="First Name"></form-field>
  <form-field formControlName="lastName" label="Last Name" controlType="dropdown">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </form-field>
  <p>Hello "{{form.get('firstName').value}} {{form.get('lastName').value}}"</p>
</form>
```

A problem with the `select` above is that `ngModel` [is already deprecated together with reactive forms](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel). Unfortunately there is nothing like `ngDefaultControl` for Angular's `<select>` control value accessor. Therefore I suggest to combine this with my first improvement idea.

Comment: Your code works only if we pass formGroup as @P. Moloney said. ngDefaultControl has no effect for me, the selector still not work and ask for a formGroup parent.

Comment: And for those who need import : import { Component, Input, forwardRef, AfterViewInit, HostListener, OnChanges, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,FormControlName, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, DefaultValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject'
import {AfterContentInit, ContentChild, Directive} from '@angular/core';

Comment: @bormat I don't need to pass the formGroup. The code here works in my applications and is very useful

Comment: can you provide an executable example, this way I will find the difference with my code?

Comment: thanks, so it is because I used angular material that I get this error, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjjydy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, I don't know why I have supposed you were using angular material too. so I can't use your method which works. In your code, there is a class  DelegatingValueAccessor but it doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: @bormat Actually I use Angular Material. Please see "Idea for Improvement 1" in my answer which covers your use case. Your code doesn't work, because you have an additional `formControlName` INSIDE your `form-field`. Please replace it by `formControl` attribute according to my "Idea for Improvement 1" and it will work.

There will be a problem with `matSelect`, but the value accessor of my example above is already prepared to fix it. Simply apply `#matSelect` (<mat-select #matSelect="matSelect" ...>) in case you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely worth diving deeper into @web-master-now's answer but to simply answer the question you just need the `ElementRef` to reference the `formControlName` to the input.

So if you have a simple form

```ts
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [this.user.name, [Validators.required]],
  email: [this.user.email, [Validators.required]]
});
```

Then your parent component's html would be

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm" no-validate>
   <custom-input formControlName="name" 
                 // very useful to pass the actual control item
                 [control]="userForm.controls.name"
                 [label]="'Name'">
   </custom-input>
   <custom-input formControlName="email" 
                 [control]="userForm.controls.email"   
                 [label]="'Email'">
   </custom-input>
   ...
</form>
```

Then in your custom component **custom-input.ts**

```ts
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-input',
    templateUrl: 'custom-input.html',
})
export class YInputItem {

   @Input('label') inputLabel: string;
   @Input() control: FormControl;
   @ViewChild('input') inputRef: ElementRef;

   constructor() { 
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
      // You should see the actual form control properties being passed in
      console.log('control',this.control);
   }
}
```

And then in the component's html **custom-input.html**

```html
<label>
    {{ inputLabel }}
</label>
<input #input/>
```

Definitely worth checking out the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html), but depending on how you are developing the control you might want to just use `@Output` to listen to change events , i.e if different inputs in the form have different events, you can just put the logic in the parent component and listen.

Comment: how is the control associated with the input element?

Comment: With this solution I am getting `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'`

Comment: @Tabares should be with this notation ```userForm.controls['name']``` and ```userForm.controls['email']```

Comment: You no need to use: name: [this.user.name, [Validators.required]], you should use name: ["", [Validators.required]] and then you can vhange value by calling setValue() or patchValue() of formGroup or formControl, also here you are passing form control, and its name, if you pssing form control so no need to pass control name, you can directly bind it with your template input, like: <input #input [formControl]="control" >

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this simple use case can help someone.

*This is an example of a phone number masking component that allows you to pass in the form group and reference the form control inside the component.*

**Child Component - phone-input.component.html**

Add a reference to the *FormGroup* in the containing div and pass in the *formControlName* like you normally would on the input.

```
<div [formGroup]="pFormGroup">
     <input [textMask]="phoneMaskingDef" class="form-control" [formControlName]="pControlName" >
</div>
```

**Parent  Component - form.component.html**

Reference the component and pass in *pFormGroup* and *pControlName* as atttributes.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Home</label>
     <phone-input [pFormGroup]="myForm" pControlName="homePhone"></phone-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input value by using the [ion-input-auto-complete](https://github.com/ZameelAmjed/ion-input-auto-complete) component, as per your code use below code

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" no-validate>
   <input-auto-complete formControlName="name"
                 [ctrl]="userForm.controls['name']"
                 [label]="'Name'">
   </input-auto-complete>
</form>
```