# how to declare a component as FormControl in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

i was trying to declare a component as Form Control.

```
<my-child-component formControlName="selectedSeats"></my-child-component>
```

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component) i tried something like this using ControlValueAccessor,

```
public propagateChange: any = () => {};
public validateFn: any = () => {};

get selectedClasses() {

    return this.myForm.get('selectedSeats').value;
}
set selectedClasses(val) {
    this.propagateChange(val);
}
public ngOnChanges(inputs) {

}
public writeValue(value) {

}
public registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
}
public registerOnTouched(fn) {
}

public validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validateFn(c);
}
```

I am trying to pass the value of **this.myForm.get('selectedSeats').value** as component value and trying to bind to formcontrolname. But this code not working neither not throwing error.

could someone please tell me how to set **this.myForm.get('selectedSeats').value** value as my-child-component value and pass to formcontrol ?

parent component is Dynamic reactive nested form. inside the parent form i am calling another child-component which has its own set of form and it will return one value and it will be stored on selectedSeats input field. So now i need to pass that field value to parent and bind on parent nested form using formcontrol.

Comment: Just a question : **why would you do that ?**

Comment: parent component is Dynamic reactive nested form. inside the parent form i am calling another child-component which has its own set of form and it will return one value and it will be stored on input field. So now i need to get that field value and bind on parent nested form as formcontrol.

Comment: Well I think you should create reactive forms based on your model, not on your components, this would be easier for you.

Comment: You have to provide the Value Accessor in the component meta data like so: `provide: [{NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    multi: true}]`

Comment: yes already those were done :(

Comment: Where is "selectedClasses" set in the child component?

Answer (score 0):

You should take formControl object instead of formControlName. Create a input in your component and take object. Your code will look like this:

```
export class MyChildComponent {
  @Input() formControlObject: FormControl;

  getControlValue(){
    return this.formControlObject.value;
  }
}
```

Now you will pass object to this component like this:

```
<my-child-component [formControlObject]="myForm.controls['selectedSeats']"></my-child-component>
```

Hope it will help