# Form field prefix/suffix/icon from component not rendering correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have created the following component in order to avoid repetition of boilerplate html that adds a prefix/suffix/icon to a form field:

```
@Component({
    selector: "fancy-input",
    template: `
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <span matSuffix>.00</span>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>'visibility'</mat-icon>
        `,
})
export class FancyInputComponent {}
```

The objective is that html like this:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
    <input matInput placeholder="How much?" formControlName="amount">
    <fancy-input></fancy-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

will produce this:
[image]

However, it seems the `<fancy-input>` element is remaining in the DOM and this is causing the prefix, suffix and icon to render incorrectly:

[image]

Is there a way to replace/remove the `<fancy-input>` element from the DOM?

I have tried changing the selector to an attribute (i.e. `"[fancy-input]"`). If I then add that to the `input` element then the outputs are rendered as children of that element and they are ignored. I cannot add the attribute to `<mat-form-field>` because that is already a component.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to include the whole `mat-form-field` in the fancy custom component, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-tp4wzt). The following code for the custom component was obtained by adapting the template and the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42744166/1009922), adding a `width` style property and processing the `input` event. Please note that the component can accommodate additional inner content.

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => FancyInputComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: "fancy-input",
  template: `
    <mat-form-field [style.width]="width">
      <input #input matInput type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [value]="value" (input)="onInput($event, input.value)">
      <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
      <span matSuffix>.00</span>
      <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-form-field>`,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
})
export class FancyInputComponent {

  // for mat-icon visibility
  hide = true;

  // width style attribute of the input control
  @Input() width: string;

  // placeholder input
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  //current form control input. helpful in validating and accessing form control
  @Input() c: FormControl = new FormControl();

  // set true if we need not show the asterisk in red color
  @Input() optional: boolean = false;

  //@Input() v:boolean = true; // validation input. if false we will not show error message.

  // errors for the form control will be stored in this array
  errors: Array<any> = ['This field is required'];

  // get reference to the input element
  @ViewChild('input') inputRef: ElementRef;

  //Lifecycle hook. angular.io for more info
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // RESET the custom input form control UI when the form control is RESET
    this.c.valueChanges.subscribe(
      () => {
        // check condition if the form control is RESET
        if (this.c.value == "" || this.c.value == null || this.c.value == undefined) {
          this.innerValue = "";
          this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = "";
        }
      }
    );
  }

  //The internal data model for form control value access
  private innerValue: any = '';

  // event fired when input value is changed . later propagated up to the form control using the custom value accessor interface
  onInput(e: Event, value: any) {
    //set changed value
    this.innerValue = value;
    // propagate value into form control using control value accessor interface
    this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);

    //reset errors 
    this.errors = [];
    //setting, resetting error messages into an array (to loop) and adding the validation messages to show below the field area
    for (var key in this.c.errors) {
      if (this.c.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key === "required") {
          this.errors.push("This field is required");
        } else {
          this.errors.push(this.c.errors[key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //get accessor
  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
    }
  }

  //propagate changes into the custom form control
  propagateChange = (_: any) => { }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    this.innerValue = value;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
  }
}
```

The parent component would include it in its template:

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="example-container">
    <fancy-input formControlName="amount1" [width]="'100%'" [placeholder]="'My amount'" [c]="form.controls.amount1" [(ngModel)]="amount1Value"></fancy-input>
    <fancy-input formControlName="amount2" [width]="'100%'" [placeholder]="'Your amount'" [c]="form.controls.amount2" [(ngModel)]="amount2Value">
        <span>Other stuff</span>
    </fancy-input>
</div>
```

with the corresponding code:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  amount1Value = 72.18;
  amount2Value = "";

  form = new FormGroup({
    amount1: new FormControl(),
    amount2: new FormControl(),
  });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your thorough answer @ConnorsFan. However, this then makes the entire `mat-form-field` a black box. I would still like the parent component to be able to customise other aspects such as hints, validation/errors, etc.

Comment: You may try to include those other aspects inside of the component, and control them with `@Input` properties, similar to the custom `width` property shown in the answer. I modified the code to allow inner content inside of the component, if needed.

Comment: Interesting approach that may get the job done. I will give that a try and see if I can generalize that approach -- in a large app there will be many similar requirements for consistency. I don't relish the idea of having to recreate this each time I want to create a new variant.