# Custom Controls with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 7, Angular Material controls with Reactive Forms.

I created custom text (matInput type="text"), number (matInput type="number"), select (matSelect) controls with Angular Material with mat-form-field

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kec8i8) for my example.

I am trying to attach the custom form controls to reactive form and trying to fire any validations on the form group automatically.

I am using ControlValueAccessor to achieve this, however my Select is not being identified as form control and no value is being recorded in the form control on the form.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component

Comment: just use `(selectionChange)="onChange($event.value)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** Jenson-button-event find a better option, see the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062444/binding-formcontrol-validators-to-a-custom-form-field/60071352#60071352)

Looking into your code, I see that you use Angular Material to create your custom FormControl. Well, The problem when use Angular material is how make that the "errors" appears.

When we use `<mat-error>` the error appears if the control is invalid. Take account that is invalid our custom form conrol, NOT the input-material. How avoid this inconvenience?

The solution is using a CustomFieldErrorMatcher. if we can create a CustomFiledErrorMatcher that take account the errors of our customFormControl, we can do some like

```
class CustomFieldErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  constructor(private customControl: FormControl) { }
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return control.dirty && this.customControl.invalid;
  }
}
```

Well, it's only in ngAfterView write some like

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ngControl: NgControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (ngControl) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.control = ngControl.control as FormControl;
      })
    }
  }
```

Has a function

```
errorMatcher() {
    return new CustomFieldErrorMatcher(this.control)
  }
```

And create our custom-formControl.html like

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value=$event;onChange($event)" 
          [placeholder]="placeholder" [disabled]="disabled"
          [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionList" [value]="option.value">
            {{ option.label }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="control?.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="control?.hasError('error')">{{control?.errors.error}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ljkmd?file=app%2Fapp-component.html) two forms, one that use a customFormControl, and another one in clasic mode

Comment: Thanks, what made me solved my problem was this sentence: "<mat-error> the error appears if the control is invalid". So, in my custom case I had to set the error up manually in the controller to make it appear on the DOM.