# Binding FormControl validators to a custom form Material Select component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbegzj) set up by way of an example.

I have a standard `input` form field and a custom field that shows a `select` bound to an array.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field class="field">
      <mat-label>City</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="City" formControlName="address1" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <app-dataset-select label="Country" [items]="countries" formControlName="countryId"></app-dataset-select>

</form>
```

The whole thing is wrapped by a form with validation:

```
 this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
    address1: new FormControl(model.address1, Validators.required),
    countryId: new FormControl(model.countryId, Validators.required)
  });
```

When I click **SAVE** I expect both fields to visibly show validation - the `FormGroup` itself says we do.

But the *Country* control does not get the *ng-invalid* state (and thus no redness) and I'm not sure why - although its something to do with angular's reactive forms kung-fu black magic...

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459617/component-for-wrap-angular-material-input-does-not-show-error-styles/58472470#58472470 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887035/custom-controls-with-reactive-forms/56893298#56893298

Comment: eeeugh. that is so obscure angular! and you wouldnt believe how many times i hit google not to find these :(

Comment: the problem is that is the custom control who has the error (you can see that Angular give the class ng-valid and ng-invalid to your custom control), not the "inner" mat-input. That's all

Comment: and how to problematically set the required attribute on mat-select in order to get the asterisk? I am still having problems...I don't see (with dev tools) in your example where the text is set to red.

Comment: see my answer about the asterisk

Comment: decent option thanks - I seem to have stumbled on a solution that does not require `ErrorStateMatcher` (see below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big thanks to @Eliseo but that solution was not working for me on my existing code (different way of binding, Angular 8?) and I was getting even more frustrated - `ngControl.control` was always undefined..

The solution does not require a custom `ErrorStateMatcher` apparently, but the answer is to ensure the `mat-select` is bound to the `FormControl` in the `FormGroup` which is fiddly due to life-cycle events, but effectively:

```
export class DatasetSelectComponent extends AbstractFormFieldComponent {
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() items!: [{id: number, label: string}];
}

export abstract class AbstractFormFieldComponent implements  ControlValueAccessor {

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  _formControl = new FormControl(); 
  onChange = (value: any) => {};

 constructor(@Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if(this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      /**
       * get a handle on the FormControl that was created in the last Reactive FormGroup in the component injection hierarchy
       * so that it can be bound to the input in our Custom Component
       * this ensures input value binding to model + explicit validation is bound
       * e.g. new FormGroup({ titleId: new FormControl(personalDetails.titleId, Validators.required) } =>
       *    <input [formControl]="this.formControl"
       * otherwise you will have to do that manually for evey single control on every single form
       * which is obviously a lot of repeating yourself
       */

      of(this.ngControl.control)
        .pipe(
          skipWhile(fc => !fc),
          take(1)
        )
        .subscribe(fc => {
          this.formControl = fc as FormControl;
          console.log(
            'Custom FormControl (AbstractFormFieldComponent): Binding to Reactive Form',
            this.ngControl,
            this.ngControl.control
          );
        });
    }

  get formControl() :FormControl|RequiredFormControl {
    return this._formControl;
  }
  set formControl(forControl:FormControl|RequiredFormControl)  {
    this._formControl = forControl;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: (value: any) => void): void {}

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if(this.formControl) this.formControl.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
  }


}
```

Note the removal of the component injection of `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`  (replaced by the workings in the constructor), which prevents a cyclical dependency compile-time error:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomSelectComponent),
    }
  ]
```

And a snippet from the template:

```
  <mat-select [formControl]="formControl" [required]="formControl.required">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
      {{ item.label }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

[Updated blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mat-select-with-custom-validators)

[image]

Comment: ¡¡AMAZING!! sure I was being work around to avoid errorMatcher some time ago and didn't find the key

Comment: I used the code in the updated Stackblitz above. The custom control works but when the FormGroup is reset it triggers a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Answer (score 3):

well, if we want an "asterisk" when required, one way to do it is that our mat-input was add [required] attribute to our inner input

```
<mat-select ... [required]="isRequired?true:null">
```

How give value to isRequired variable?

Well, I like use in constructor and ask about if there are an attribute(*)

```
  constructor(@Attribute('required') required, public injector: Injector) {
    this.isRequired=required!=undefined
  }
```

And we use our custom component like

```
<app-custom-select placeholder="My State" formControlName="state" 
     [optionList]="stateList" required>
</app-custom-select>
```

In that case we can not included the Validators.required

A [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ljkmd-dxivkq?file=app%2Fcustom-select%2Fcustom-select.component.ts) that include the * if required

(*) we can use a simple @Input too, but @Input must be used only if we want change the value dinamically

Comment: Yes decent option - I've extended `FormControl` as another option