# Angular Custom Form Control with Custom Validator Sync Issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-controls, angular-forms, angular15

Custom control component implementing both ControlValueAccessor and Validator interface.

This custom control is unable to display error properly from the consumer component's validators.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    },
  ],
  template: `
    <article style="border: 1px solid green; padding: .5rem ">
      <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
        <input formControlName="telInput" placeholder="Telephone" (blur)="onFocusOut($event);">
      </form>
    <section class="code">
      inner errors: {{ inputForm.get('telInput')?.errors | json }}
    </section >
</article>
  `,
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  inputForm!: FormGroup;

  formCallbacks = {
    onChange: (anyVal: any) => {},
    onTouched: () => {},
    onValidatorChange: () => {},
  };

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.inputForm.setValue({ telInput: obj });
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.formCallbacks.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.formCallbacks.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.inputForm.disable() : this.inputForm.enable();
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log('[inner] validate', control.errors);
    return control.errors;
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.formCallbacks.onValidatorChange = fn;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputForm = this.fb.group({
      telInput: [''],
    });
    this.inputForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.formCallbacks.onChange(val.telInput);
    });
  }

  onFocusOut(event: any) {
    this.formCallbacks.onTouched();
  }
}
```

However when this custom control is used with a reactive form and a validator,
the errors are not syncing properly between the component form and custom input.

```
function someValidator(ac: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  if (ac.value === null) {
    return null;
  }
  const inputVal = ac.value;
  const noErrorsOk = inputVal.length > 2;
  const err = inputVal !== null && noErrorsOk ? null : { dataFormat: true };
  console.log('[outer] validator err', err);
  return err;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CustomInput, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <article>
      <form [formGroup]="mainForm">
        <custom-input formControlName="joesNumber"></custom-input>
      </form>
      
      <section class="code">
        outer error: {{ mainForm.get('joesNumber')?.errors | json }}
      </section>

      <section>
        <p>Notes: length > 2 is valid. inner error is always null and outer error is alwasy dataFormat error. </p>
      </section>
    </article>
  `,
})
export class App {
  mainForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      joesNumber: ['', [someValidator]],
    });
    this.mainForm.statusChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log('[outer] statusChange', val);
    });
  }
}
```

playground

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3zwvin

Answer (score 0):

When we create a custom form control with Validator is to make a function validator that it's not the same that the errors we pass when create the formControl. you can not return the control.errors

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (control.value=="fool")
        return {innerError:"I'm can not be fool"}
    return null;
  }
```

If you want to give a class to your input if the formControl is invalid you can declare a variable control

```
control!:AbstractControl
```

And give value in the validate function

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (!this.control)
        this.control=control
    ...
  }
```

So write some like

```
<input [class.invalid]="control?.errors"/>
```

**Update**

There're another way to "reach" the "outher control", we can get the control using injector and get it in ngAfterViewInit

```
  constructor(private injector:Injector,...){}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ngControl: any = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (ngControl) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.outerControl = ngControl.control as FormControl;
      })
    }
  }
```

The setTimeout is to not get the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

In this way, using a ErrorStateMatcher like this a [bit old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459617/component-for-wrap-angular-material-input-does-not-show-error-styles/58472470#58472470), we can manage the mat-input and the mat-error in the mat-form-field

Rewrite the code with a few changes

```
class CustomFieldErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  constructor(private customControl: FormControl) { }
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return this.customControl && this.customControl.touched && this.customControl.invalid;
  }
}
```

So we can use a mat-form-field

```
<article style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 0.5rem">
  <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        formControlName="telInput"
        placeholder="Telephone"
        matInput
        [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher()"
        (blur)="onFocusOut($event)"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="outerControl?.hasError('required')">
        Required
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="outerControl?.hasError('isFool')">
        I'm can not be fool
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</article>
```

See how we can show one or another error using the "outerControl"

Note also that the inner FormControl not declare with any validator, you use the `validate` function

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wokvku?file=src%2Fcustom.input.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Findex.html)

Well, this work in several cases, but we can also not create a custom form control else a custom form field control like show the guide [Custom form field control](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)

So, our component implements

```
export class MyCustomFieldControl implements ControlValueAccessor, 
                                      Validate, 
                                      MatFormFieldControl<MyCustomFieldControl>,
                                      OnDestroy{
}
```

Comment: understood part1 of answer about validate fn. How can I get errors from consumer of this custom-input(joesNumber)  and show those errors in custom-input component itself. If you look at validate fn logs, the control.errors value state changes one keystroke after the joesNumber state change.
Btw I'm using mat-error with ErrorMatcher in Custom Input component.

Comment: i did something like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qucdxo

Comment: @vito, sorry for the delay (really I've been very bussy). I update the answer to indicate how "reach" the "outer control" and how use a formField of material. I hope this help you. NOTE: Really, if you want , you can use an unique FromControl instead of a FormGroup.