# Angular 8: formControlName inside component multiple nested levels below

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

Using this resource, I want to implement formControlName up multiple nested levels.

[Angular 2 - formControlName inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Say the actual formGroup lives 3 component levels above a child formControlName component,

ControlValueAccessor works if the Parent component is right next to child. However multiple levels above (grandfather) form does not work.

Is there an alternative to Service, or multiple input/outputs ? Or are these the only method?

```
A--> Component with formGroup 
   B---> Component container
      C---> Component container
        D ---> Component with FormControlName (should pass to Component A)
```

Component A will collect multiple form control names from different children components similar to this,

**InputText.ts**

```
export class InputTextComponent implements  AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor  {
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Output() saveValue = new EventEmitter();

  value: string;
  onChange: () => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value ? value : "";
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {this.onChange = fn}

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {this.onTouched = fn}

  setDisabledState(isDisabled) {this.disabled = isDisabled}
}
```

**InputText.html**

```
 <input .. />
```

Comment: question is unclear - can you make *lives 3 levels above a child* more explicit i.e. are these nested components, what is your form? You can make components that pass along whole formgroup values (or mapped values)

Comment: the     <form [formGroup]="..."> lies 3 components above the formControlName in the Dom tree

Comment: Actually you are not obliged to use `formControlName` you can simply use `formControl.get('path.to.prop')` for the controls.

Comment: hi @Sergey can you write in example, and I can send points? I have Angular 8 by the way;' is it good practice to do what suggested? or more deprecated practice? thanks again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can consider four options:

**1) provide ControlContainer on your component with FormControlName**

**d.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
export class DComponent implements OnInit {
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/HXoyuXOrCn1XrgtJYoLv?open=app%2Fd%2Fd.component.ts)**

**2)** **create simple directive that provides ControlContainer**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[provideContainer]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
export class ProvideContainerDirective {
}
```

then place this directive somewhere at the top of nodes hierarchy in your

**d.component.html**

```
<ng-container provideContainer>
  <input formControlName="someName">
</ng-container>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/iG1wCrb97b1dMr3OtF6l)**

**3) use FormControlDirective instead of FormControlName directive**

[FormControlDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective) requires [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) instance to be passed

```
<input [formControl]="control">
```

You can get this instance either though DI:

**d.component.ts**

```
export class DComponent implements OnInit {
  control;
  constructor(private parentFormGroupDir: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.parentFormGroupDir.control.get('someName');
  }
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/67Tld4ZlGVpOZ7fFsHEo)**

or use some service that ties your components.

**d.component.ts**

```
export class DComponent implements OnInit {
  control: FormControl;

  constructor(private formService: FormService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.formService.get('someName');
  }
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/oz0RstAis0oDR9NL1pxR)**

**4) pass FormGroup as Input props down to the children or get it through DI or service and then wrap your input[formControlName] with formGroup directive**

**d.component.html**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
 <input formControlName="..."
</ng-container>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/pYt5hxU0IFtZf5f7t3Wl?open=app%2Fd%2Fd.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/forsoanswer-nestedformcontrol)

i think this is what you're looking for

follow the stackblitz example

I've created 3 components `comp1` `comp2` `comp3`

I've created the signup form in `appModule` and passing the `formGroup` to `comp1` => `comp2` => `comp3`

In `comp3` I've created `formControl` of `age` property and binding it.
On changing the value of `age` from `comp3` it will get reflected in parent component, that is `appComponent`

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: yeah, I'm always aware of multiple input/output, and services, just curious if there is an alternative, thanks