# Angular 8: Send Form data as a Service to Another Component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

How do I sent all the Formgroup data as a Service in Angular to Another Component? I am looking for alternative to ControlValueAccessor. So anytime someone writes something on a form, the receiver will get the value data.

Trying to edit the code below to work.

**Address Sender Form:**

```
export class AddressFormComponent implements OnInit {

  editAddressForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'streetName' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)],
      'city' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)],
      'state' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)],
      'postalCode' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   // What should I write as Event Code??
}
```

**Service:**

```
export class AddressService {

  private messageSource = new Subject();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(currentMessage) {
    this.messageSource.next(currentMessage);
  }
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
export class AddressCombinedReceiverComponent implements OnInit {

  message: any;

  constructor(private readonly addressService: AddressService) {
    this.addressService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => this.message = currentMessage);
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Related question: [Angular 2 - formControlName inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component)

Comment: Have you tried reactive forms valueChanges observable to capture value changes? https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesnt look far away from what you need, in your AddressFormComponent try the following. Ensure to clean up the subscription when needed, added below.

```
public subs = new Subscription();
public editAddressForm: FormGroup;

constructor(addressService: AddressService){}

public ngOnInit(): void {

  this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'streetName' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)],
    'city' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)],
    'state' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)],
    'postalCode' : [null, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]
  });

  this.subs.add(this.editAddressForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => 
  {
    this.addressService.changeMessage(this.editAddressForm);
  }));
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void
{
  this.subs.unsubscribe();
}
```

That should in turn push the data to the subject you have an in turn cause the subscribers of that subject to receive the data. To confirm try the following

```
export class AddressCombinedReceiverComponent implements OnInit {

  public message: any;

  constructor(private readonly addressService: AddressService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.addressService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => { 
      this.message = currentMessage;
      console.log(this.message); // should be the form coming through
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to respond to an event. `FormGroups` already have an observable that streams the changes.

Example

```js
// address-form.component.ts
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  editAddressForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // cleanup
    this.addressService.formValues$ = null;
  }

  constructor(private addressService: AddressService) {
    this.editAddressForm = new FormGroup({
      streetName: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]}),
      city: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]}),
      state: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]}),
      postalCode: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]}),
    });

    this.addressService.formValues$ = this.editAddressForm.valueChanges;
  }
}
```

```js
// address.service.ts
export class AddressService {
  formValues$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() { }
}
```

In regards to the receiver, if the intention is to show the form changes in the template, then I recommend using the async pipe for that, so that you only subscribe when it's defined, like:

```js
// address-combined-receiver.component.ts
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit {
  addressValues$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private addressService: AddressService) {
    this.addressValues$ = this.addressService.formValues$;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- address-combined-receiver.component.html -->
<ng-container *ngIf="addressValues$ | async as addressValues">
  <pre>{{ addressValues | json }}</pre>
</ng-container>
```