# Angular 8: Form-Control, No value accessor for form control with name: 'StartDateForm'

Tags: html, angular, forms, datepicker

My code is as given below:

```js
export class SearchByParametersComponent implements OnInit {

  parametersForm=new FormGroup({

    NumAppForm:new FormControl (''),

    UniqeIDForm :new FormControl (''),

    StartDateForm :new FormControl (''),

    EndDateForm :new FormControl (''),

    NumStatusForm :new FormControl (''),

  });

 

showAll()

  {

    //x:string

    debugger;

    this.NumApp=this.parametersForm.controls.NumAppForm.value;

    this.x=this.parametersForm.controls.UniqeIDForm.value;

    this.NumStatus=this.parametersForm.controls.NumStatusForm.value;

   this.sd=this.parametersForm.controls.StartDateForm.value;

    // this.sd= this.parametersForm.get('StartDateForm').value;

    // this.ed=this.parametersForm.controls.EndDateForm.value;

    console.log(this.parametersForm);

    if (this.NumApp==undefined) {

      alert("חובה לבחור מספר מערכת");

    }

    else

    {

      if (this.x!="" && this.x!=undefined)

      {

        this.ParametersToSearch.NumApp=this.NumApp;

        debugger;

        this.ParametersToSearch.UniqeID=String(this.x);

        debugger

        this.checkUniqeId.emit(this.ParametersToSearch);

        debugger;

        this.ParametersToSearch=new ParametersToSearchDTO();

        debugger;

          //this.checkUniqeId.emit(x);  

      }

      else  if (this.StartDate != null  && this.EndDate != null)

       {

          this.DateObject.StartDate=String(this.StartDate["day"]+"-"+this.StartDate["month"]+"-"+this.StartDate["year"]);

          this.DateObject.EndDate=String(this.EndDate["day"]+"-"+this.EndDate["month"]+"-"+this.EndDate["year"]);

          this.DateObject.NumApp=this.NumApp;

          debugger;

          this.checkRangeDate.emit(this.DateObject);

          this.DateObject=new DateRangeDTO();

          debugger;    

      }

      else  if(this.NumStatus!="" && this.NumStatus!=undefined)

      {

        debugger;

        this.StatusSearch.NumApp=this.NumApp;

        this.StatusSearch.NumStatus=this.NumStatus;

        this.checkStatus.emit(this.StatusSearch);

        this.StatusSearch=new StatusSearchDTO();

        debugger;

      }

      else 

      {

        debugger;

        this.checkNumApp.emit(this.NumApp);

        debugger;

      }

    }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="parametersForm">

     <div class="myPage">

               <div class="form-group title1">

                    <span> קוד מערכת <span class="must" title="שדה חובה">*</span></span>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title2">

                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="NumAppForm"

                         (change)="onChangeApp($event.target.value)" required>

                         <option>----------</option>

                         <option *ngFor="let index of ListApp">{{index}}</option>

                    </select>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title3">

                    <span dir="rtl"> UniqeId </span>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title4">

                    <input class="form-control"  formControlName="UniqeIDForm" type="text">

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title5">

                    <span class="line"> צרוף קובץ מ</span>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title6">

                    <app-date-picker formControlName="StartDateForm" (dateSelect)="dateSelectStart($event)"></app-date-picker>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title7">

                    <span class="line"> עד</span>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title8">

                    <app-date-picker  formControlName="EndDateForm" (dateSelect)="dateSelectEnd($event)" ></app-date-picker>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title9">

                    <span> סטטוס</span>

               </div>

               <div class="form-group title10">

                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="NumStatusForm" (change)="onChangeStatus($event.target.value)">

                         <option>----------</option>

                         <option *ngFor="let index of ListStatus">{{index}}</option>

                    </select>

               </div>

     </div>

</form>

<button type="submit" dir="ltr"  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showAll(); reset()">אישור</button>




<!-- <input class="radio" type="checkbox" title="הכנס UniqeId" label="הכנס" />  <br> -->

<!-- [(ngModel)]="NewUniqeId.value" -->

<!-- formControlName="StartDateForm" -->

<!-- formControlName="EndDateForm" -->

<!-- [formControl]="parametersForm.controls.StartDateForm" -->
```

a project on Angular 8:
I have a DATE-PICKER tag in HTML
And I have FORM-CONTROL that contains more tags like:
INPUT, SELECT ...
All the FORM-CONTROL elements are identified
By the FROM-CONTROL-NAME attribute
But only the DATE-PICKER element is unknown at all and makes an error when trying to set the FROM-CONTROL-NAME property to it
what can we do?
I need to know it in FORM so I can clear all content with elements with one click .....

Answer (score 0):

The `app-date-picker` is not a form control and as such cannot set the `formControlName`. The component should implement `ControlValueAccessor` to work as a form control. If you need to build custom form controls, please refer

[Angular 2 - formControlName inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661430/angular-2-formcontrolname-inside-component)